# How to publish a second collection based on data in first

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am struggling to return a publication to a specific author based on data field in the first mongo query.

In the below the Posts subscription works absolutely fine, but the Authors subscription never returns anything. I am assuming it has something to do with async code.

```
Meteor.publish("postAndAuthor", function (postId) {
  check(postId, String)
  var post = Posts.find({_id: postId});
  var authorId = post.authorId;

  return [
    book,
    Authors.find({_id: authorId})
  ];

});
```

Comment: The `find` function returns a cursor, not an array or object. Change your `Posts` query to use `findOne`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:
As the comment Brian stated, I am treating the post variable an object not a cursor. Publications require cursors are returned though so the best way to get the authorId is using

```
var authorId = post.fetch()[0].authorId;
```

Answer (score 0):

When publishing a subscription you should be returning a cursor. Try this instead:

```
Meteor.publish("postAndAuthor", function (postId) {
  check(postId, String)
  var post = Posts.find({_id: postId});
  var authorId = post.authorId;

  return Authors.find({_id: authorId}):
});
```